# Connect the same items in listView (C#)

Tags: c#

I am just in the process of creating the program 'System ordering pizza'. (in WinForms) At this point, I create a 'basket' with the products that the user chose.

If the user selects a product (click on picture), it will be added to the listView1. (For example: Margheritta, quantity: x1).

but if I choose the same product again, it's added as again. (For example: Margheritta, quantity: x1).

I'm trying to make it come together. Can anyone help me solve this problem?
(For example: Margheritta, quantity: x2).

```
public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pizza0 = "Margheritta";

    ListViewItem pizza = new ListViewItem(pizza0);
    pizza.SubItems.Add("x1");
    listView1.Items.Add(pizza);
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `ListViewItem` every time you click that button

Comment: You should check if the item is already in the ListView and if so, only change the subitem index from 1 to 2

Comment: You should create a data source with a proper model. Then bind that data source to the ListView instance.

Comment: What's going on? This is at least the [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142219/) [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144418/) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184855/) over the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to get the number of pizzas currently added, and then add +1 for the current pizza that was added.

```
using System.Linq;

public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pizza0 = "Margheritta";

    ListViewItem pizza = new ListViewItem(pizza0);

    // get the number of pizzas in the listview that are named "Margheritta":
    int pizzaCount = 0;
    pizzaCount = listView1.Items.Where(x => x.Name == pizza0).Count();

    // or, if you can't use LINQ:
    foreach (var item in Items) {
        if (item.Name == pizza0)
            pizzaCount++;
    }

    pizza.SubItems.Add("x" + (pizzaCount + 1));
    listView1.Items.Add(pizza);
}
```

Comment: ListView.ListViewItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `using System.Linq;` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @IamNguele I have this added and I still get this error.

Comment: @Beata Xx I updated the answer to show how to loop through and get the count, instead of using LINQ.